# Why are strings on Twitter starting with $ marked as tags?

Tags: twitter

As you can see on https://twitter.com/powtac/status/277190821479063552, strings with four letters starting with an `$` are marked as a Tag on twitter. But what kind of tags are those `$TAGS`?

[image]

Comment: Completely off topic: there is a "dollar tag sign" UTF-8 symbol: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0024/index.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's part of the stock exchange search feature. Or "[cashtags](http://money.cnn.com/2012/07/31/technology/twitter-cashtag/index.htm)".

When you include a dollar sign followed by the stock ID it will take you to a search page that shows you related Tweets about the [company for that ticker symbol](http://www.cnbc.com/id/48416772/Twitter_Rolls_Out_Stock_Search_Feature).

> Now you can click on ticker symbols like [$GE](https://twitter.com/search?q=%24GE&src=ctag) on http://twitter.com  to see search results about stocks and companies
>
> [@twitter](https://twitter.com/twitter/status/230098997010911233)

Since there are a lot of the stock exchange identifiers with four characters, that's why you're seeing it appear auto-linked in your Tweets.

Normal currency and dollar amounts don't contain letters like that in that position and is also why that convention was adopted by Twitter.